# Can unbound electrons jump energy levels?

Tags: electromagnetism, photons

If an unbound electron (or indeed any charged particle) is moving through free space, is there a probability that it can spontaneously change energy by emitting a photon, or does this require the presence of an external potential $A_4$.

The important point is that the process is spontaneous, like jumping energy levels in an atom.

I'm pretty sure this violates some conservation law but I just want to check.

Answer (score 6):

**Short answer:** No. You can't make the system respect both energy and momentum conservation.

**Longer answer:** In the presence of another charged particle it *is* possible, but that's arguably not "free space".

---

*Aside:* In free space there are no discrete "levels", it's a continuum.

Comment: Ta! This helps me with my problem.

Comment: The quick way to see that there is no way to emit a photon is to go to the rest frame of the electron. Then it should be pretty clear that you can't emit a photon make the energy/momentum conservation work.